# Storing small size big quantities image on hdfs for later processing

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, tensorflow, hbase, hdfs

I am working on a project at which we have a billion of images with their metadata on MongoDB.  I want to store this image on HDFS for later image processing. The size of image is between 500K to 4MB, thus, I have the problem of small files with Hadoop. I found 3 main possible solutions for this problem which are HBase, har or sequence files.  What is best suitable solution knowing that I need to use Spark in processing these images rather than Map-Reduce?

Comment: Spark can read directly from MongoDB... Or Sequence files will work fine

Comment: so i can read the data with spark , process them with tensorflow

Comment: I have no experience with tensorflow, but I don't see why not. You only need Spark to read data into an RDD / dataframe